# Gulp.js - Deploying MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, gruntjs, gulp

For my current project I use Grunt as a full-deploy system. Checking/compiling all assets, cleaning cache, and deploying database. Now I am looking at Gulp.js. Everyone says, it has much more readable configuration file and it executes a bit faster. The only thing is missing for me - database deployment. With Grunt, I am using grunt-deployments package. Is there something like that for Gulp? Or should I write my own package?

Comment: "readable configuration" is up to the reader. gulp uses code instead of configuration where Grunt uses config (but both are just javascript in the end). Also "executing faster" highly depends on what you're doing. Most grunt/gulp tasks use the same dependency, so if one is slow, likely the other will be too. So not "everyone says" these things. ;)

Comment: Well, as I thought. Because every time something new appears, everyone gets excited. Including me.) Will just stick to the good old Grunt. Thanks for your helpful opinion!

Answer (score 0):

Gulp is a build system. *Build* and *Deploy* are separate sets of activities. Steaming is good for building lots of smallish files like in an assembly line in manufacturing. For deployment,  synchronous code ([nodejs is not good at synchronous, atleast until v0.12](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-execsync-a-synchronous-api-for-child-processes/)) is good.

I use powershell(windows) or shell/chef/ansible(linux) for deployment/setup/etc, which call gulp for building assets pipeline.

Gulp is mostly targeted towards assets pipeline in other tech-stacks, and full build system for node-js techstack.

However, If you have only trivial deploy tasks, then consider using async.series() from async package and use regular node-js code to do the deployments. Accept and call the `done` callback when you are done in the gulp task.